# Baking normals of high poly torus to low poly?

Tags: normals, texture-baking, normal-map

Why does my torus keep baking normals like this? Ive tried unwrapping without stretching the uvs but it gets the same result, high poly is just the same torus with subd applied. What else could be the problem here?[image]

Comment: are you talking about the angles? If your low-poly has angles (because you've not given it a Subdivision Surface modifier) it will be the result

Comment: Okay i thought something looked wrong but I guess not! Thanks

Comment: the bake rays will be perpendicular to the low-poly faces, so if you don't give it Subdivision Surface modifier it will create these angles, if you give it Subdivision Surface it will be round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angles we see are the angles of the low-poly. Let's say that you have this high-poly and this low-poly:

[image]

If you bake the high-poly to the low-poly, as the rays of the bake will go perpendicularly to the faces of the low-poly, and as there is an angle between these faces, you'll have this result:

[image]

If you give a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your low-poly though, it will add virtual faces and you'll have a smooth result:

[image]

Comment: So modifiers are taken into account when baking normals even if theyre not applied?

Comment: Yes that's it....

Comment: merci moonboots!